# Bigquery: UNNEST suddenly does not work anymore

Tags: google-bigquery

This works:

```
SELECT 
count(*)
FROM 
session.session_20170101 AS s 
cross join UNNEST (s.pageviews) AS pages
```

And this works:

```
SELECT
count(*)
FROM
`session.session_*` AS s
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX = '20170101'
```

But this doesn't:

```
SELECT 
count(*)
FROM 
`session.session_*` AS s 
cross join UNNEST (s.pageviews) AS pages 
WHERE 
_TABLE_SUFFIX = '20170101'
```

Error: Name pageviews not found inside s at [4:26]

However, The last query was working fine about a week ago.  I had the query saved, and re-running it no longer works.  It seems like I can use _TABLE_SUFFIX and cross join UNNEST seperately, but when I use both it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that your table wildcard expands to include some tables that have an incompatible schema with the rest of them. Since your table names correspond to `YYYYMMDD` strings, you can include more of the YYYY part to work around the incompatible tables. For example:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT pageview
FROM `yourdataset.sessions_20*`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.pageviews) AS pageview
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '160101' AND '170101';
```

Comment: This works:
`SELECT
  pages.url AS url,
  operational_key
FROM
  session.session_20170101 AS s
  cross join UNNEST (s.pageviews) AS pages`
This doesn't:
`SELECT
  pages.url AS url,
  operational_key
FROM
  \`session.session_*\` AS s
  cross join UNNEST (s.pageviews) AS pages
WHERE
  s._TABLE_SUFFIX = '20170101'`
(Error: Name pageviews not found inside s at [6:24]) Am I misusing _TABLE_SUFFIX somehow?  Seems to be correct based on documentation and this exact same saved query did work a few days ago.  Thanks.

Comment: also, pageviews is not a different table, but is nested inside session

Comment: After a bit of debugging, I think the issue is that the wildcard expands to include some tables that have a different schema (they're missing `pageviews`, for instance). To fix the problem, include more of the prefix in the wildcard pattern; see if my updated answer helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @elliottBrossard, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.  Even restricting it to a single table (single day) doesn't fix it and I'm positive there are pageviews for that day.  In fact, I can query pageviews for that day if I don't use _TABLE_SUFFIX.  Please see the updated question.

Comment: That wasn't what I suggested, though--you need to use a longer prefix after `sessions_`, such as `sessions_20*`. Did you try that?

Comment: just tried `SELECT 
    count(*)
    FROM \`session.session_20*\` AS s 
    cross join UNNEST (s.pageviews) AS pages 
    WHERE 
    _TABLE_SUFFIX = '170101'`.  That fails for the same reason, but will work if I remove the cross join line, or if I remove the _TABLE_SUFFIX restriction and replace it with the specific table name.

Comment: Okay, it seems like the problematic table must be from 2016. If you use `session.session_2017*` I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks @elliott!  That fixed it.  Am I correct in assuming that the schema of all tables that match the wildcard must support the query, even if those tables would be filtered out by the _TABLE_SUFFIX?

Comment: That's my understanding, anyway. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/wildcard-tables#when_to_use_wildcard_tables) says that the tables should have compatible schemas. In your case, you may also be interested in [partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables), which always have a consistent schema that applies to all partitions.

Comment: Note that the schema used for querying purposes is the schema of the most recently created table that matches the pattern in the FROM clause (*before* the _TABLE_SUFFIX filter is applied). https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#schema_used_for_query_evaluation